# How to prohibit standard users performing administrative tasks having typed administrative passwords?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, privileges

In Windows 10, if a user on a standard account attempts to perform a task that requires administrative privileges, they are asked to type in a password of an administrative account, on behalf of which they may perform this task, provided they type in the password correctly.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior, that is, to prohibit standard users from performing administrative tasks and prevent them from being asked for an administrative password? So that they cannot perform administrative tasks no matter what, as long as they're logged into a standard account?

Comment: In Linux, I can prohibit others from using `su`, so I doubt I'd be unable to do sth similar in Windows...

Comment: Your regular users shouldn't know the admin passwords.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You are right of course, but despite that I still think in my special case this what I want to do is justified :)

Comment: There may be some sort of a shell tweak that hides the "Run as administrator" option

Comment: @timotree Won't help much :( Merely launching many apps (like System COnfiguration) or clicking many options in Control Panel tend to trigger this prompt for admin passwd, not only clicking on Run as administrator

Comment: I would definitely agree with @JourneymanGeek .  This is much more of a personnel management or HR issue than it is a Systems Administrator problem.  We are always glad to help whenever possible, but the *real* solution to this problem involves changing the admin passwords and letting standard users know that inappropriate behavior on the Windows systems won't be tolerated.  The end-users wouldn't be happy with a Windows 10 machine [configured to use kiosk mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions).

Comment: It's possible on Windows 7 using secpol, see [Hide User Account Control prompts for non-administrative users](http://resetchangewindows7password.com/prevent-standard-users-from-getting-windows-7-uac-administrators-passwords-prompts.htm). This will **Automatically deny elevation requests**. I don't have a copy of Windows 10 to see if this works there as well.

Comment: @DavidPostill , I just double-checked and that group policy is available on a Windows 10 Pro machine, also.

Comment: @Run5k Thanks. I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there any way to prohibit standard users from performing administrative tasks?

> and prevent them from being asked for an administrative password?

Yes this is possible using the Security Policy Editor (`secpol`).

See the instructions below.

Note:

- Although the instructions are aimed at Windows 7 that particular group policy is also available on a Windows 10 Pro machine.

---

#### Hide User Account Control prompts for non-administrative users

> Follow these steps to eliminate UAC prompts for standard users:
>
> - Click on the start menu, type "secpol.msc" and hit Enter.
> - When the "Local Security Policy" editor ("snap-in") opens, double-click on "Local Policies" -for those affecting this particular
>     machine- and double-click on "Security Options".
> - Scroll down until you see a node labeled "User Account Control: Behavior of the Elevation Prompt for Standard Users" (careful, another
>     policy starts with the same name, but actually affects computer
>     administrators!) Double-click on it and the following dialog will
>     open:
>
>   [image: Customize Windows 7 UAC prompts behavior for standard users]
> - The default behavior for standard users, selected in the dropdown menu pictured above, is "Prompt for credentials": whenever elevated
>     privileges are required, they'll need to select an administrator and
>     enter its password in a UAC prompt to proceed with the action.
> - Click on the dropdown, and select the "Automatically deny elevation requests" option instead; click "OK" to apply the new
>     setting: from this point on, standard users won't event get a UAC
>     prompt when they attempt any task that needs administrative
>     permissions.
>
> Note that this setting takes effect immediately, so make sure that you
>   and/or someone else does have the full administrator credentials,
>   which will sooner or later be needed to logon to that computer. While
>   this is a very secure setting, that eliminates possibilities even for
>   those who have admin name and password, it can also become very
>   impractical, especially for advanced "power" users, who'll find their
>   computing experience quite frustrating! Be sure to see how you can
>   also hide usernames and only show blank text boxes on the Windows 7
>   logon screen for an even safer computer.

Source [Prevent standard users from getting the Windows 7 UAC / administrator password prompt](http://resetchangewindows7password.com/prevent-standard-users-from-getting-windows-7-uac-administrators-passwords-prompts.htm)